# What is PHP exit()/die() equivalent in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

What is the PHP's equivalent of `die()/exit()` funciton in Node.js?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: sometimes it is funny, when folks criticize `php`, while such untold primitive things (like `exit` and many other things) are not available in those "advanced" languages. in node.js unfotunately, you have to `if/return` from tens of functions correctly to `exit` . And moreover, how on earth, `return` (which should return different value) can be way for `exit`.. unbelievable.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`process.exit()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) is the equivalent call.

Comment: They are not equivalent. PHP's `die()` does not terminate the server as Node.js' `process.exit()` does, it merely stops terminating remaining code in the file. There is no equivalent, unfortunately.

Comment: @MMiller That is partially true because PHP has a totally different architecture. PHP has originated from CGI, in which case (i.e. single process executing the CGI script) it seems to be exactly equivalent to me as it stops the process. I consider FCGI and similar technologies merely as optimization than as gamechangers regarding this question. I therefore think your issues are quite nit-picky and not reflecting real-world problems IMO. Quite similarly, you could say that running multiple supervisord-started note instances behind a reverse proxy would make `process.exit()` not stop the server.

Comment: You can also use `return` if you are not in a function. There are some differences however. See my answer for more details. @MMiller I think this might be more what you mean?

Comment: @nl-x AFAIK using return outside of a function is pretty much equivalent to process.exit(), but he seems to be looking for a function that terminates the entire "server" whereas such things do not really exist for CGI-like applications such as PHP.

Comment: Once you call `die` in one script, you can still access other scripts. `die()` kills the script, not the entire web server. This can't be an equivalent.

Comment: @AnuraagVaidya What you want to do is to terminate only the current request. That is, however, dependent on the server library you want to use. For example, for Koa see https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/response.md (you need to specify a response code).

Still, it's *not* the equivalent to `die()`. `die()` kills the current process. `process.exit()` kills the current process. The difference in function is due to how people use PHP (= CGI) and NodeJS (= Server process handling all requests). You could, in principle, run NodeJS as CGI, but nobody really does that.

Comment: @T.Todua Why? Please explain.

Comment: Since you also need to `require()` the library, a simple one-liner is `require('process').exit();`

Answer (score 28):

I would use `throw`. Throw will cause the current request at hand to end, and will not terminate the node process. You can catch that output using your error view.

```js
throw new Error('your die message here');
```

Comment: The advantage of `throw` compared to `process.exit()` is IMO that you have an error message. The disadvantage (or, sometimes, an advantage), is that it might be catched somewhere. Therefore I wouldn't consider it as a `die()` equivalent, but as an alternative for many usecases that one should consider.

Comment: Up-vote this! I'd much rather `throw` and get my `catch` in order instead of nuking the entire web server.

Comment: @AvadData That clearly depends on your use-case. The question is clearly for an equivalent to `die()`, whereas `throw` would be an equivalent to `throw`...

Comment: Agreed that these are different. A throw could be caught, and the expectation of immediate exit would not occur. Given the push towards catching every exception in upcoming nodejs, the use of throw for immediate exit would not serve this purpose. You could easily do a throw, catch it and in the catch, do a process exit. A bit verbose, but you get all your cases handled (nice error message and immediate exit).

Comment: Smart, although there is also another limitation other than what @UliKöhler mentioned. 
`throw`ing doesn't support expression usage, therefore you simply can't drop it in everywhere. Well, at least until this proposal lands into language https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions

Comment: Does this work no matter where it is within code that uses async/await?

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, it will work within an async function. However, if the function is returning a promise, then the `reject('your die message here')` function should be called instead.

Answer (score 7):

It needs to report to stderr (rather than stdout) and exit with a non-zero status to be die() ...

```
function die (errMsg) 
{
    if (errMsg)
        console.error(errMsg);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If not in a function, you can use:

```
return;
```

But you can also use the suggestion of [@UliKöhler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21185215/1209443):

```
process.exit();
```

There are some differences:

- `return` ends more graceful. `process.exit()` more abrupt.
- `return` does not set the exit code, like `process.exit()` does.

Example:

```
try {
    process.exitCode = 1;
    return 2;
}
finally {
    console.log('ending it...'); // this is shown
}
```

This will print `ending it...` on the console and exit with exit code 1.

```
try {
    process.exitCode = 1;
    process.exit(2);
}
finally {
    console.log('ending it...'); // this is not shown
}
```

This will print nothing on the console and exit with exit code 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the npm package [dump-die](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dump-die).
I took a look at the package on github and it practically uses `process.exit(1)`.

Firstly, install it by `npm install dump-die`. It has a `dd()` function.

```
let foo = 'bar'
let hodor = { hodor: 'hodor' }
dd(foo, hodor)
// returns
// 'bar'
// { hodor: 'hodor' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

`return false`
After the block you want halt.
For example:

```
if(something<=0)
    return false;
```

This will stop the operation. Because JS works on browser you can't stop the page process at certain point. This is re-operable.
Use your imagination as requirement to use this.