# How to stop current page process only, not the whole NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, die

The question may sound clumsy because I don't know how to put it in words. Please take a look at this example:

```
//PHP
<?php
    die( "The PHP process stops here. The PHP is still running" );
    insert_into_database_someinfo(); //This function will not be executed
?>
```

My question is: What is equivalent to die() or exit() in PHP for Nodejs, **without stopping the whole current nodejs server**? I found the owner of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185152/what-is-php-die-equivalent-in-node-js) having the same issue but the suggestion of using `process.exit()` is not appropriate.

`process.exit()` will stop the entire server.

The following code attempts to output to the browser, but unlike PHP `die()`, this will continue onto the next lines

```
req.end( 'This is an output to the browser' );
insert_into_database_someinfo(); //This function will still be executed.
```

I would consider this to be somewhat comparable to `echo()` in PHP, because everything keeps going. I would like to output info, then stop the process there (just the current request, not the whole nodejs server).

Please advise.

Comment: funny, there is no equivalent in node.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a `return` to stop the execution of your function :

```
if (nogood) {
    req.end( 'This is an output to the browser' );
    return;
}
insert_into_database_someinfo();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. However, it won't work (or it could be my mistake). I tried to do `res.end( 'Email invalid' ); return; insert_into_database_someinfo();` and it still runs.